# keras access layer parameter of pre-trained model to freeze

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, lstm, keras-layer

I saved an LSTM with multiple layers. Now, I want to load it and just fine-tune the last LSTM layer. How can I target this layer and change its parameters?

Example of a simple model trained and saved:

```
model = Sequential()
# first layer  #neurons 
model.add(LSTM(100, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(X.shape[1], 
X.shape[2])))
model.add(LSTM(50, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(25))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam')
```

I can load and retrain it but I can't find a way to target specific layer and freeze all the other layers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have previously built and saved the model and now want to load it and fine-tune only the last LSTM layer, then you need to set the other layers' `trainable` property to `False`. First, find the name of the layer (or index of the layer by counting from zero starting from the top) by using `model.summary()` method. For example this is the output produced for one of my models:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_10 (InputLayer)        (None, 400, 16)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_2 (Conv1D)            (None, 400, 32)           4128      
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_2 (LSTM)                (None, 32)                8320      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 33        
=================================================================
Total params: 12,481
Trainable params: 12,481
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Then set the trainable parameters of all the layers except the LSTM layer to `False`.

Approach 1:

```
for layer in model.layers:
    if layer.name != `lstm_2`
        layer.trainable = False
```

Approach 2:

```
for layer in model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

model.layers[2].trainable = True  # set lstm to be trainable

# to make sure 2 is the index of the layer
print(model.layers[2].name)    # prints 'lstm_2'
```

Don't forget to compile the model again to apply these changes.

Answer (score 2):

An easy solution would be to name each layer, i.e.

```
model.add(LSTM(50, return_sequences=True, name='2nd_lstm'))
```

Then, upon loading the model you can iterate over the layers and freeze the ones matching a name condition:

```
for layer in model.layers:
    if layer.name == '2nd_lstm':
        layer.trainable = False
```

Then you need to **recompile** your model for the changes to take effect, and afterwards you may resume training as usual.